# Como faço para retornar dinamicamente os dados das colunas do MySQL em cada input de um formulário de atualização?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

### Descrição

Primeiramente, o campo `Seleciona jogo` retorna todos os jogos cadastrados (Esse campo funciona como a seleção do ID do jogo para atualizar determinado jogo) e o que eu gostaria de saber é como **fazer para que os outros campos abaixo do `Seleciona jogo` sejam preenchidos dinamicamente os valores que estão nas colunas do banco de dados para facilitar o processo de atualização**.

### Vantagens disso:

- Economiza tempo, pois o usuário escolhe o campo que quer atualizar sem precisar em preencher alterar os outros campos.

### Exemplo:

- Seleciona jogo: `Watch Dogs 2` (ID).
- Nome: `Watch Dogs 2` (valor que está na tabela jogo da coluna `nome`).
- Preço: `23,99` (valor que está na tabela jogo da coluna `preco` seja mostrado automaticamente no campo `Preço`).
- Plataforma: `PC` (valor que está na tabela jogo da coluna `plataforma` seja mostrado automaticamente no campo `Plataforma`).
- Desenvolvedora: `Ubisoft` (valor que está na tabela jogo da coluna `desenvolvedora` seja mostrado automaticamente no campo `Desenvolvedora`).
- A único campo que vou atualizar é o `preco`, de `23,99` para `19,99`. Depois disso aciono o botão de `Atualizar jogo` e pronto, nem precisei preencher os outros campos que não queria atualizar (pois seu eu deixar os campos em branco as colunas ficam vazias no banco, exceto a coluna `preco`).

### A imagem do formulário

[image: A imagem]

### Código PHP

```
<?php
        require_once 'conexao.php'; 
        if(isset($_POST['Atualizar'])){  
            $cd_jogo = $_POST['cd_jogo'];
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $preco = $_POST['preco'];
            $plataforma = $_POST['plataforma'];
            $desenvolvedora = $_POST['desenvolvedora'];
            try {
                $update = "UPDATE jogo SET nome = :nome, cpf = :cpf, preco = :preco, 
                plataforma = :plataforma, desenvolvedora = :desenvolvedora WHERE cd_jogo = :cd_jogo";
                $atualiza = $conexao->prepare($update);
                $atualiza->bindValue(':cd_jogo',$cd_jogo);
                $atualiza->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
                $atualiza->bindValue(':preco',$preco);
                $atualiza->bindValue(':plataforma',$plataforma);
                $atualiza->bindValue(':desenvolvedora',$desenvolvedora);
                $atualiza->execute();   
            } catch (PDOException $falha) {
                echo "A atualização não foi feita".$falha->getMessage();
            }
        }
        $seleciona = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_jogo, nome FROM jogo");
        $resultado = $seleciona->fetchAll();
    ?>
```

### Formulário

```
<form method="POST">
        <p> Seleciona jogo:
        <select name="cd_jogo" required="">
            <option value=""> </option>
            <?php
                foreach ($resultado as $v) {
                    echo "<option value='{$v['cd_jogo']}'>{$v['nome']}</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> Preço: <input type="number" name="preco" step="10.00" required=""> </p>
        <p> Plataforma: <input type="text" name="plataforma" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> Desenvolvedora: <input type="text" name="desenvolvedora" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Atualizar" value="Atualizar jogo"> </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Se possível, tente ser mais objetivo e específico em sua dúvida. Pelo que entendi, não precisa desse contexto

Comment: Pra minha pergunta não ser fechada eu tinha que trazer o máximo de informações possíveis da minha dúvida pro pessoal entender.

Comment: As informações precisam ser específicas da dúvida. Mas vamos lá, você quer selecionar uma opção do select com a label "Seleciona Jogo" e os campos seriam preenchidos dinamicamente; é isso?

Comment: @LeonardoNegrão exatamente, conforme o que está preenchidos nas colunas de determinado ID do jogo.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar te ajudar

Comment: O preenchimento dinâmico serve também funciona pra campos do tipo ```<select>```? Eu queria fazer isso futuramente.

Comment: Tipo a coluna ```Plataforma``` eu queria colocar um ```<select>``` com uns ```<option>``` com as opções de ```PC```, ```PS4``` e ```Xbox One``` e fazer esse preenchimento dinâmico nesse ```<select>```, pois a ```<option>``` por padrão sempre será vazia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para preencher os campos dinamicamente, ou seja, sem que recarregue, você precisa usar javascript. E o primeiro passo é entender melhor o DOM para marcar corretamente seus respectivos campos, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
//solução com JQUERY
//detecta o manuseio do select
$(document).on('change','#cd_jogo',function(){
//coleta o resultado do select
valor = $(this).val();
//aqui você precisa fazer a requisição para coletar os resultados no seu backend em PHP e trazer um JSON parecido com o que está abaixo; você pode usar ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
if(valor == 1) {
//o retorno do PHP precisa ser um objeto de JSON parecido com esse abaixo para preencher os campos
retornoPHP = '{ "nome":"Jogo1", "Preco":10, "Plataforma":"console", "Desenvolvedora": "desenvolvedora" }';
}
if(valor == 2) {
//o retorno do PHP precisa ser um objeto de JSON parecido com esse abaixo para preencher os campos
retornoPHP = '{ "nome":"Jogo2", "Preco":20, "Plataforma":"console", "Desenvolvedora": "desenvolvedora" }';
}
if(valor == 3) {
//o retorno do PHP precisa ser um objeto de JSON parecido com esse abaixo para preencher os campos
retornoPHP = '{ "nome":"Jogo3", "Preco":30, "Plataforma":"console", "Desenvolvedora": "desenvolvedora" }';
}
// Parse do json para você trabalhar os atributos separadamente
var obj = JSON.parse(retornoPHP);
//Adicionando os resultados aos respectivos campos
$('#nome').val(obj.nome);
$('#preco').val(obj.Preco);
$('#plataforma').val(obj.Plataforma);
$('#desenvolvedora').val(obj.Desenvolvedora);
//esse preenchimento é o "trazer automático"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
        <p> Seleciona jogo:
        <select name="cd_jogo" id="cd_jogo" required="">
            <option value="1">1</option>  
            <option value="2">2</option>  
            <option value="3">3</option>  
        </select>
        </p>
        <p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> Preço: <input type="number" name="preco" id="preco" step="10.00" required=""> </p>
        <p> Plataforma: <input type="text" name="plataforma" id="plataforma" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> Desenvolvedora: <input type="text" name="desenvolvedora"  id="desenvolvedora" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Atualizar" value="Atualizar jogo"> </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Perceba que na linha ```echo "<option value='{$v['cd_jogo']}'>{$v['nome']}</option>";``` é tipo um array com todas as chaves da tabela, enquanto que vc especificou no seu JQuery a quantidade de chaves, como eu mudaria ```if(valor == 1) {
retornoPHP = '{ "nome":"Jogo1", "Preco":10, "Plataforma":"console", "Desenvolvedora": "desenvolvedora" }';``` para o meu caso?
}

Comment: Não tem problema que o preenchimento seja com dados do backend; o frontend sempre interpretado pelo navegador como HTML, CSS e JS. A questão é que você precisa se acostumar com o conceito de fazer requisições assíncronas com Ajax

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento nenhum em Ajax, aindou estou aprendendo Javascript

Comment: para que suas aplicações tenham mais vida, JS é mais importante que PHP; como pode ver no exemplo que mostrei, os eventos funcionam tranquilamente

Comment: Estou tendo dificuldades em executar o código, tipo vc definiu 3 ```<option>``` no formulário e existe um if pra testar a existência de cada ```<option>``` no JSON, mas no meu código eu uso o foreach pra gerar os id's evitando o uso de tanto ```<option>```, onde eu não entendi como refazer essa parte.

Comment: Fora isso o código é bom, só me confundiu um pouco por causa no campo de ```Seleciona jogo```.